# Angular momentum from spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, probability

I have came across the following question:

> Two particles, each of spin 1, are at rest.  It is known that the $z$ component of the spin of each is zero.  Show that the probability that the total angular momentum of the system is zero is 1/3.  What is the probability that the total angular momentum is $J= 1$?

I am unsure how to go about this problem as I don't know how to calculate these probabilities. Is there a trick with using $J = |l-s| , |l-s|+1, . . .,|l+s|$?

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute 
$$|1,0 \rangle \otimes |1,0 \rangle = \sum_{J,m} \langle J,m|1,0;1,0 \rangle |J, m\rangle$$
where $\langle J,m|1,0;1,0 \rangle$ are Clebsch-Gordan coefficients. Indeed there are selection rules, and your comment shows that $J = 0,1,2$. Likewise you can easily show that only $m=0$ can appear. So you need to look up 3 possible CG coefficients (if you're really smart, you can argue that $J=1$ does not appear using an additional selection rule, so you only need to look up 2).

Comment: Thank you. So adding and squaring the CG coefficients gives the probability?

Comment: Indeed - that's the way to go.

Comment: I knew there was something simple and obvious that I was missing

Answer (score 1):

Correction:
Clearly M=0.
There are three such states:
$$ S=2: 2|0,0\rangle+|-1,1\rangle+|1,-1\rangle; \\
S=1: |1,-1\rangle -|-1,1\rangle; \\
S=0: |-1,1\rangle+|1,-1\rangle- |0,0\rangle; $$.
The probability that S=1 is zero.

Comment: This is plain wrong. For instance, the $J=1$ probability is 0.

Comment: From the CG coefficient's, $C_{1,-1} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}, C_{0,0} = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}, C_{-1,1} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}$. Adding and squaring gives the desired 1/3

Comment: @HansMoleman You are correct. I changed my answer.